# JavaFX,SQLite : How to Set BLOB Value in update Query?

Tags: java, sqlite, javafx, sql-update, blob

I'am getting a problem whene i execute upadate query , the problem is whene i wante to update the blob column im my sqlite table, i notice that only the path this blob file are stored. but whene is use insert query with binding value like that :`pst.setBinaryStream(File);` it works fine!

I get my blob file with this code :

```
File image=null;
URL photoURL = null;
try {
    photoURL = new URL(addadh_adherent_photo_label.getText());
} catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(ParametresController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}

try {
    image= new File( URLDecoder.decode( photoURL.getFile(), "UTF-8" ) );
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(ParametresController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} 
FileInputStream   fis = null;
try {
    fis = new FileInputStream(image);
} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(ParametresController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

and  here is my update query :

```
  int AderentId =100; 
  String updateAderent=" UPDATE gss_aderent SET"
                        + "ad_photo='"+image+"'
                        + "WHERE ad_id='"+AderentId+"' ";
  stmt.executeUpdate(updateAderent);
```

My problem is  : The updated value isn't  a blob value but just his path:(  my question is how to store(update) blob value in update  query ? does exist a method to bind BinaryStream parametre for update query ? can i use preparedStatement in update query ?

Comment: given that your `updateAderent` statement has syntax errors, you shouldn't be able to store anything...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your application looks like it's open to [SQL Injection attacks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Preventing_SQL_Injection_in_Java)

Use a PreparedStatement and [setBlob(int x, InputStream in)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setBlob(int,%20java.io.InputStream))